# Button not displayed in the right place

Tags: python, button, layout, resize, pyqt

I am using PyQt to create a desktop application. I am trying to create a button using hbox and vbox, but it doesn't display unless I give the specific command:

```
  button1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Exit", self)
```

But, by doing this, the vbox and hbox functionality doesn't seem to function.
**I need the button to be on the bottom-right corner of the window, which stays there even after window-resize**.
With this code, it is positioned on the top-left corner.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
class Trial(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Trial,self).__init__()
        self.createUI() 
    def createUI(self):     
        button1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Exit",self)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.close)
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)  #stretches it to the right end of the page
        hbox.addWidget(button1)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)  #stretches it to the bottom end of the page
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        button1.resize(button1.sizeHint())
        self.setGeometry(300,200,750,450)
        self.setWindowTitle('Testing')
        self.show()        
def main():
    app= QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    w=Trial()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

If I use `button1.move(420, 400)`, it moves the button to the position I want, but it doesn't stay there when I re-size the application window.

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me - i.e. the button stays in the bottom-right corner when resizing. So the problem(s) must be elsewhere in your code. Please post a small, self-contained example that reproduces the issues you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The example code doesn't work because you are trying to set a layout on the main window, which already has a layout.

Instead, you need to add a central widget, and then set the layout on that:

```
def createUI(self):
    self.setCentralWidget(QtGui.QWidget(self))
    ...
    vbox.addLayout(hbox)
    self.centralWidget().setLayout(vbox)
    self.setGeometry(300,200,750,450)
    ...
```